# MemoryCache get/set and assigning to variable

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, caching, thread-safety

I have been testing some code locally and read through quite a bit of SO posts but I am a bit confused still how MemoryCache works in certain scenarios. So the question relates to the following code:

```
 class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        test.TestingMethod();
    }

}

public class Test
{
    private readonly MemoryCache MemoryCache = MemoryCache.Default;
    private CacheItemPolicy policy = null;
    private CacheEntryRemovedCallback callback = null;

    public void TestingMethod()
    {
        var ints = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            ints.Add(i);
        }

        callback = this.MyCachedItemRemovedCallback;
        policy = new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default,
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(2),
            RemovedCallback = callback
        };

        MemoryCache.Set("ints", ints, policy);
        var intsCached = (List<int>) MemoryCache.Get("ints");
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)).Wait();
        MemoryCache.Set("ints", new List<int>() {1}, policy);

        foreach (var intCached in intsCached)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(intCached);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    void MyCachedItemRemovedCallback(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Expired");
    }
}
```

In the console output of this TestMethod I am getting
Expired
1 - 1000 on separate lines

Why would I get the 1-1000 instead of only the 1 that we set after expiration? Doesn't this list refer to the same ref?

Comment: Please read [Meta: Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: Updated to my main question only

Comment: This behaviour has nothing to do with MemoryCache. You've stored a list with 1000 items in to the variable `intsCached`. That's all. Everything else is noise. If you refetch from MemoryCache and iterate that collection, it will have 1 item.

Comment: Isn't that a reference to the memory cached list though? That's not a copy of what's stored in MemoryCache from what I have read?

Comment: It's a reference to a list that was once also stored in MemoryCache, but is no longer.

Comment: Got it, I think for whatever reason I am thinking because its the same entry in the Cache it's the same object. Even if I SET before its expired to a new list, the variable still references the old list. Like you said reference to the old list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MemoryCache` (or any other entity that stores values) will not magically update content of the List when you set entry with the same name to different value. I.e. what if you do `MemoryCache.Set("ints", 42, policy);` instead?

Looks like you expect value (`intsCached`) to be computed long after it is assigned to:

```
  var intsCached = (List<int>) MemoryCache.Get("ints");
```

`intsCached` is computed at that line and no longer know where it comes from.

If you want to have "variable" that remembers where it comes from and always get latest value from that location - use `Func` to compute it every time:

```
  Func<List<int>> intsCached = () => (List<int>) MemoryCache.Get("ints");
  ...
  foreach (var intCached in intsCached()) 
  ...
```